# How to change the map and erase all the blitted sprites?

Tags: python, maps, pygame, sprite, tile

I'm working on an RPG and after completing my first map, I had to put the possibility of passing from one to another because I don't want to use scrolling.

Actually I check if the position of my character is the same as a particular sprite (door, invisible block, etc.) and then doing the change of the font and the loading of the new `*.txt` file. But the problem is that the previous sprites are still there!

I checked some way to solve this problem and a lot of people said that I should use the `fill()` function to overlay the screen. It works but the old sprites are still there; if my character tries to go to where a wall was, he can't.

I also try emptying the list of the sprites but it crashes the game instead, as the character was in this list, even if I reload the character...

It's the only thing blocking me to achieve a test version of the universe, if anyone could help me..

Here is my game loop :

```
    while continuer_jeu:

            #Limit the speed
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == QUIT:
                            continuer_jeu=0
                            continuer_accueil=0
                            continuer_rules=0
                            continuer=0
                            carte=0

                    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                            #If user press escape => back to the title screen
                            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                                    continuer_jeu = 0

                            #Chara's moving key
                            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                                    Noc.deplacer('droite')
                            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                                    Noc.deplacer('gauche')
                            elif event.key == K_UP:
                                    Noc.deplacer('haut')
                            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                                    Noc.deplacer('bas')

            #Refresh with new positions
            fenetre.blit(fond, (0,0))
            niveau.afficher(fenetre)
            fenetre.blit(Noc.direction, (Noc.x, Noc.y))
            pygame.display.flip()

            if niveau.structure[Noc.case_y][Noc.case_x] == 'ma6': #If going through a door
                    if carte == "n1": # if first map
                            fond = pygame.image.load(image_Interieur).convert()
                            niveau = Niveau("Maison") #Load the house sprites
                            niveau.generer()
                            niveau.afficher(fenetre)
                            fenetre.blit(fond,(0,0))
```

If you need more of the code, just ask.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to be doing neither of the things you discuss in the question; also, the fact that the variables and comments are in French is a bit of a challenge! However, note that `fill` removes the sprites from the screen, but *not from the list of sprites*, so you can still collide with them even if they aren't drawn. You could separate the character from the list of other sprites, then empty the latter list when switching between rooms.

Comment: Yes, I try the several ideas but none of them fulfilled what i wanted to do so I remove them each time. Haha, sorry ! I totally forgot that point ^^' I'm going to translate it.
Oh, i remember of that idea with collide the sprites, but i didn't though that would work on a complete list. I'll try it later !

Comment: Hi ! I tried to do what you advise me but I can't figure out how to make separate list for character before using `empty(niveau.structure)` or `pygame.sprite.groupcollide(niveau.structure,newniveau.structure, ,dokill, dontkill)` ...I'm really bad with groups and so on...x_x'

Answer (score 0):

I achieve to pass from a map to another by deleting the previous list, load an other one and then recreate the character :

```
            if niveau.structure[Noc.case_y][Noc.case_x] == "up" :
                    if carte == "n1" :
                            fond = pygame.image.load(image_Map2).convert()
                            niveau = Niveau("n2")
                            niveau.reset()
                            niveau.generer()
                            niveau.afficher(fenetre)
                            Noc = Perso("image/Noc right.png", "image/Noc left.png","image/Noc face.png", "image/Noc back.png", niveau)
                            fenetre.blit(fond,(0,0))
                            carte = "n2"

            if niveau.structure[Noc.case_y][Noc.case_x] == "down" :
                    if carte == "n2" :
                            fond = pygame.image.load(image_Map1).convert()
                            niveau = Niveau("n1")
                            niveau.reset()
                            niveau.generer()
                            niveau.afficher(fenetre)
                            Noc = Perso("image/Noc right.png", "image/Noc left.png","image/Noc face.png", "image/Noc back.png", niveau)
                            fenetre.blit(fond,(0,0))
                            carte = "n1"
```

with theses functions :

```
class Niveau:
    def __init__(self, fichier):
            self.fichier = fichier
            self.structure = 0
    def reset(self):
            self.structure = []

    def generer(self):
            with open(self.fichier) as fichier:
                    self.structure = [ligne.split() for ligne in fichier]
```

But I got an other problem : I can't change the map a second time. On the 2nd map, the character reach a down case, nothing happend. I tried to put the instruction when it is "down" on a "up" + "if carte == "n2" but the character came back to his spawn position... Where could I have made mistakes ?